# Ubuntu 14.04 does not work wifi for Lenovo Y50-70

Tags: wireless, lenovo, ubuntu-drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 to my computer (lenovo Y50-70) but wifi doesnt work. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you install the proprietary BCM driver (open "Additional drivers" from dash).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes works if you enter `rfkill list all` and find wifi is hard blocked
`sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop`
`sudo rfkill unblock all`

I know they are working on a patch for the ideapad_laptop module to fix the rfkill issue when a hardware switch doesn't exist